# How to doOnNext only consumes the first n items of a PublishSubject?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2, rx-android, android-jetpack-compose, rx-kotlin

I have a `PublishSubject`:

```
val myPublishSubject = remember {
    PublishSubject.create<Long>().apply {
        doOnNext {
            Logger.debug(TAG) { "Got new Long $it" }
        }
            .takeUntil(someObservable)
            .subscribe()
    }
}
```

and I have a service what gets a stream of Long values, somewhere in another function:

```
while(notFinished){
    val newLong = getSomeLong()
    myPublishSubject.onNext(newLong)
}
```

Here, the upper `doOnNext{}` is logging forever. How can I for instance only allow first 20 Long values? `.take(20)` did not work!

Comment: It should be `take(20)`. What does `remember { }` do?

Comment: @akarnod2  remember - allows you to remember state from previous recompose invocation. See Jetpack-Compose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`take(20)` should work, this test passes:

```
@Test
fun consumeOnlyFirst20ValueTest() {
    val ps = PublishSubject.create<Long>()

    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
        for (i in 1L..1000L) {
            ps.onNext(i)
            delay(50)
        }
    }

    var i = 0
    ps.take(20)
            .doOnNext {
                i++
            }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe()

    Thread.sleep(6000)
    assertEquals(20, i)
}
```